# Rotate a 2D surface around an axis to generate a 3D volume

Tags: mesh, 2d

I have a **collection of discrete points** that describe a surface $S$ as in the image below.

[image: Surface]

I would like to revolve the surface around the x-axis to create a volume. Is it possible to do it in Blender?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just build that surface by adding a plane, add a subdivision surface modifier and move the vertices as you need it.
Then use screw modifier and change screw value and rotation as you need it.

To your second question in comment: I think, this is only possible with python.

To "quickly draw" vertices on a "plane" simply add a plane.

2. Go to *edit mode*
3. Press <kbd>7</kbd>
4. *Mesh -> merge -> at center*
5. Tap <kbd>E</kbd> and drag mouse to next point and release mouse
6. Repeat step 5 until you got your shape

---

2nd possibility:

Add *Bezier Curve*

2. Press <kbd>7</kbd>
3. <kbd>↹ Tab</kbd> > *Edit mode*
4. <kbd>X</kbd> *>Vertices*
5. Tap on draw in left menu
6. Draw your shape
7. Hit <kbd>↹ Tab</kbd>
8. *Object -> convert -> mesh*

Comment: Thank you @Chris. I followed your instructions and it worked great! I have no prior experience with Blender but is it possible to create a plane with subdivisions from eg a list of vertices? The shape that I am working with is rather complex.

Comment: you are welcome